# Wampserver XMLHttpRequest cannot load No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, ajax, apache, http, wampserver

First, apologies for asking a question which has been asked many times before but I haven't found a suitable answer that I understand or works for me.

I'm trying to access another service on my WAMP box but I keep getting the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://192.168.0.2:8080/json.htm?type=command&param=switchlight&idx=9&switchcmd=Off&level=0.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://192.168.0.2' is therefore not allowed access.

I'm running WAMP 2.5 on a Windows 8.1 machine. I've tried various solutions but being a bedroom hobbyist I'm running into trouble.

I've added mod_headers to Apache options and my httpd.conf contains:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
</IfModule>
```

Tried adding a .htaccess file with:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Tried using JSONP but the service I'm trying to access doesn't support it and returns a syntax error :

I've changed my code around a lot but what I'm currently using looks like:

```
<script>
    var testSwitchValue = 0;
    function testSwitch() {
        if (testSwitchValue > 0) {
            var switchCommand = "Off";
            testSwitchValue = 0;
        } else { 
            var switchCommand = "On";
            testSwitchValue = 1;
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://192.168.0.2:8080/json.htm?type=command&param=switchlight&idx=9&switchcmd=' + switchCommand + '&level=0',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Oddly it's just started to work in IE 11.0 but still not Chrome and only for the local address of 192.168.0.2.

Comment: Are you sure your `.htaccess` file being load?

Comment: I guess it's being loaded... it's in the root of my WWW folder with all my all other files.

Comment: What kind of file is your .htm file? as you see you pass arguments to it. Maybe its a faked php?

Comment: It's a pretty basic index.html file.

Comment: Maybe header mod is not enabled in your apache.

Comment: Header mod is enabled in Apache options.

Comment: Then try this: rewrite your file to php, and add to the first line `<?php header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"); ?>`

Comment: I've actually tried that as well but I'll try again when I get back.

Comment: Tried the PHP header and that doesn't work either.

Comment: Mhh. Then I dont know, I'm sorry.

Comment: Ok, thanks for taking a look anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so after some more Google searches I'm now able to answer my own question.

What I needed to do was setup a proxy in Apache and pass it my local 192 address.

Obviously being a hobbyist with no real coding experience I have no idea if this is a bad idea or not (hopefully someone may tell me) but it works and it's really only for my own entertainment/use anyway.

So in Apache I enabled:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
```

In my httpd.conf I added:

```
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /homeAutomation http://192.168.0.2:8080
ProxyPassReverse /homeAutomation http://192.168.0.2:8080
<Location /EMBackend>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

And my jQuery now looks like:

```
<script>
    var testSwitchValue = 0;

    function testSwitch() {

        if (testSwitchValue > 0) {
            var switchCommand = "Off";
            testSwitchValue = 0;
        } else { 
            var switchCommand = "On";
            testSwitchValue = 1;
        }

        $.ajax({
            url: '/homeAutomation/json.htm?type=command&param=switchlight&idx=9&switchcmd='+switchCommand+'&level=0',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data + ' ' + URL)
                },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(status);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ok now I know what you are actually doing**

I have a feeling that

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

will not work on a non standard port i.e. it assumes port 80 and you are using `http://192.168.0.2:8080`

I think you can prove this by adding another line like this

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://192.168.0.2:8080"
   Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT"
</IfModule>
```

If it suddenly starts working, then thats your problem.

Comment: Not had a lot of time to try everything you listed but I have tried changing the url parameter to what you suggested and it returns an error: http://192.168.0.2/json.htm?type=command&param=switchlight&idx=9&switchcmd=On&level=0 404 (Not Found).... because it doesn't include the port? The service I'm connecting to is my home automation kit and it's that what runs on port 8080 which I guess is giving me the issue as it's port cross domain.

Comment: Apache is listening on port 80... it's my other service which is listening on port 8080.

Comment: Oh well that would have been usefull information to put in the original question. If you want a good answer you need to provide all the relevant information.

Comment: Ok I rewrote my answer, based on the new information in the above comment. I had a feeling that `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"` did not allow non standard ports but I was side tracked by what I assumed.

Comment: Yes, your right I should have included that in the question... sorry. I added the other line in my .htaccess file and it didn't work. I then added it into my httpd.conf file and it still doesn't work. Thanks for taking a look at this.

Comment: I've changed my local address to my public address (82.XX.XXX.XX) and updated my httpd.conf file with only the Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" & Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods: "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT". My jQuerry code also includes my public address ('http://82.XX.XXX.XX:8080/json.htm?type=command&param=switchlight&idx=9&switchcmd=' + switchCommand + '&level=0') I also deleted my .htaccess file and then restarted WAMP and it works ok IN IE 11 using the 82.XX.XXX.XX but not Chrome. If I then try and use the local address in IE it will then stop working.

Comment: Continued from above: I guess whatever address I use in my jQuery code is the one that'll work in IE but neither work address work in Chrome. Is this because I'm hard coding the full address? I need to hard code it because I need to attach the port number of the other service.

Comment: Are you sure you are not falling foul of this [Chrome bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=67743). Have you tried using Firefox and/or Safari

Comment: Could be but after 3 days of trying to get it to work I'm happy with the solution I've implemented above (it's not a commercial project just a play thing). It may not be ideal but for the time being it works and I can always revisit this at a later date if needs be. Thank you for taking the time to try and help me... I really do appreciate it :)